# C# - Problem with Order of static Initializers

Tags: c#

I have the below class

```
 public class OracleStoredProcedures
{
    public static readonly string GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_BY_ID = $"{PRODUCT_PACKAGE_NAME}.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_BY_ID";

    public static readonly string GET_LATEST_PRODUCTS = $"{PRODUCT_PACKAGE_NAME}.GET_LATEST_PRODUCTS";

    public static readonly string GET_ADDRESS_BY_ID = $"{ADDRESS_PACKAGE_NAME}.GET_ADDRESS_BY_ID";

    private static readonly string PRODUCT_PACKAGE_NAME = "DATABASE.PRODUCT_PKG";

    private static readonly string ADDRESS_PACKAGE_NAME = "DATABASE.ADDRESS_PKG";
}
```

I am having the issue when trying to call the field

```
var getProducts = OracleStoredProcedures.GET_LATEST_PRODUCTS;
```

So, I did google search and found the same issue here [Order of Static Constructor/Initializers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185384/order-of-static-constructors-initializers-in-c-sharp)

In my case, these are just packages and stored procedures, not doing any complex things. I am having multiple packages and stored procedures and I just gave two as examples.

So, what is the best way to write and call these from anywhere in the code base ?

Comment: You said you have a “problem” and have “the issue.” Mind telling us what the issue *is*?

Comment: Why do the last 2 fields (`PRODUCT_PACKAGE_NAME` and `ADDRESS_PACKAGE_NAME`) have to be defined as `static readonly` when they can merely set as `const` and solve your problem along the way?

Comment: @haim770 That solves the problem I had. but can you please explain more.

Comment: Just change the order of the fields..... declare these first:PRODUCT_PACKAGE_NAME, ADDRESS_PACKAGE_NAME..... Seems like in this scenario order matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static initializers within a class are executed in textual order. Currently the interpolated string literals are being formatted while `PRODUCT_PACKAGE_NAME` and `ADDRESS_PACKAGE_NAME` have their default values of null. So you *could* just rewrite this as (fixing the names to be more conventional at the same time):

```
public class OracleStoredProcedures
{
    private static readonly string ProductPackageName = "DATABASE.PRODUCT_PKG";    
    private static readonly string AddressPackageName = "DATABASE.ADDRESS_PKG";

    public static readonly string GetAllProductsById = $"{ProductPackageName}.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_BY_ID";
    public static readonly string GetLatestProducts = $"{ProductPackageName}.GET_LATEST_PRODUCTS";
    public static readonly string GetAddressById = $"{AddressPackageName}.GET_ADDRESS_BY_ID";
}
```

Alternatively, you could make the two package names `const` fields, at which point they don't need to be initialized separately. In fact, *all* of these could be declared as `const` if you use string concatenation instead of interpolation:

```
public class OracleStoredProcedures
{
    private const string ProductPackageName = "DATABASE.PRODUCT_PKG";    
    private const string AddressPackageName = "DATABASE.ADDRESS_PKG";

    public const string GetAllProductsById = ProductPackageName + ".GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_BY_ID";
    public const string GetLatestProducts = ProductPackageName + ".GET_LATEST_PRODUCTS";
    public const string GetAddressById = AddressPackageName + ".GET_ADDRESS_BY_ID";
}
```

At that point, the compiler will validate that you aren't introducing a cycle between the constants.