# c# initialize static variable from different classes

Tags: c#

What I have is:

```cs
public static class IDs {

    public static string someID { get; set; }

    static IDs() {
        log.info(someID);
        // use someID here
    }
}

public class otherClass {

     public void otherMethod(string sym) {
         IDs.someID = sym;
     }
}
```

and then using an instance of `otherClass` like this:

```cs
otherClassInstance.otherMethod("someStringSymbol");
```

I dont have any build errors, but  `log.info(someID);` is printing `null`.
I was expecting it to be `someStringSymbol`.

Comment: The order in which static constructors happen is not defined. (The order in which static *initializers* happen is, but even then not across classes.) The ill-defined order, as well as the near impossibility to recover from errors in them, should be a strong disincentive against using static constructors period, but especially when you're going to introduce dependencies. Prefer instances with a clear initialization time, even if you make those singletons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185384/order-of-static-constructors-initializers-in-c-sharp

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. Please edit your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The static constructor is called before the `someID` property is set. This is the expected behaviour. The property cannot be set before the type has been initialized.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get `someStringSymbol` in `IDs` constructor so I can utilize it in `IDs` class. All this ,if possible, without changing `IDs` class to  non-static

Comment: why in the constructor? if the variable is static, you could have a (private) static method that uses that field whenever it gets a new value set... is this what you'd like to do?

Comment: Per my understanding , I put that in constructor because of my comment below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the static constructor [is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors).

This means that when an instance of `otherClass` invokes `IDs.someID = sym;` **the first operation that gets executed is the static constructor**, i.e. the code inside `static IDs()`.

**At this point the static variable has not yet been initialized**, and you are basically executing `log.info(null);`.

After the static constructor completes, the variable is initialized, so you should be able to see its value inside `otherMethod`, after the first reference of `IDs`.

---

Given the OP's requirement:

*I want to use the value passed in `someID` in a switch statement*

The solution could be to simply execute a static method whenever a new value is set, with the help of [explicit getters and setters](http://johnstejskal.com/wp/getters-setters-and-auto-properties-in-c-explained-get-set/):

```cs
public static class IDs
{
    private static string _someID; // backing field

    public static string SomeID
    {
        get { return _someID; }

        set
        {
            _someID = value;
            DoSomethingWithSomeID();
        }
    }

    private static DoSomethingWithSomeID()
    {
        // Use SomeID here.

        switch (IDs.SomeID)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public void OtherMethod(string sym)
    {
        // This will set a new value to the property
        // and invoke DoSomethingWithSomeID.
        IDs.SomeID = sym;
    }
}
```

`DoSomethingWithSomeID` will be invoked every time someone sets a new value to `SomeID`.

Comment: So how can we initialize `someID` at same time as executing constructor `static IDs`

Comment: do you just want to log the value of `someID`?

Comment: No, I want to use it in a `switch` statement and based on the value passed in `someID` from `someStringSymbol` ,  construct `xPath` of several UI elements in `IDs` class

Comment: are the references to those UI elements static fields?

Comment: Yes , thats the challenge I am facing currently. Initially I used static but now as requirements changed , I need to construct `xPath` dynamically

Comment: @user1207289 I edited my answer, see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I have not tried it yet , I am going to now , but what if these `xPaths` are not in a method. Will I require to put them in `DoSomethingWithSomeID`  method. Currently they are just in  class `IDs` , not in a method.

Comment: It's fine as long as these `XPath`s are static

Comment: It goes inside `DoSomethingWithSomeID` and prints value of  `SomeID` but does not gives me value of `SomeID` in `OtherClass` but it may be because of how I am accessing `xPaths` through a separate class instance. I am thinking static class may not work for this as mentioned below in one of the answer.

Comment: I have marked yours as an answer as it now prints the value of `SomeID`

Answer (score 1):

I dont think what you are trying to do is suited to static classes. I would try the following

```
public class IDs{

    public string someID{ get; set; }

    public IDs(string someId){
        this.someID = someId;
        log.info(this.someID);
           //use someID here
    }
}

pulic class otherClass{


     public otherMethod(string sym){
                IDs id = new IDs(sym);
            }
      }

public class anotherClass{

                //access instance of otherClass in wrp and call otherMethod()
               wrp.otherMethod("someStringSymbol")
         }
```

Comment: If I do this , then I will have to change reference of `IDs` at several places because I am making it non-static from static. I want to avoid that.